# Define a command including paranthesis and brackets

Tags: macros

I would like to define a command using another one to make it short. But the old command includes paranthesis and square and curly brackets. For example

```
\oldlongcommand[A](0:4){B}
```

I would like to define a command named `new` and write `\new(A,0,4,B)` or `\new{A,0,4,B}` to make it short. I tried to write simply

```
\newcommand{\new}[4]{\oldlongcommand[#1](#2:#3){#4}}
```

But it is not working.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: With your current definition you cannot use `\new{A,0,4,B}` but you must use `\new{A}{0}{4}{B}`. Something like `\newcommand*{\new}[1]{\newaux#1\relax} \def\newaux#1,#2,#3,#4\relax{\oldlongcommand[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}` might go in the right direction, but it can depend on how the old command is defined, and whether the arguments can be commas or not.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working. The arguments are just as I write. There is a `:` in the paranthesis. can it be the reason?

Comment: @campa  You did not obey syntax according to `\oldlongcommand`'s parameter text. I think it could be:  `\newcommand*{\new}[1]{\newaux#1\relax} \def\newaux#1,#2,#3,#4\relax{\oldlongcommand[#1](#2:#3){#4}}`

Comment: @UlrichDiez Absolutely true. The troubles of copy-pasting snippets `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

You defined:

```
\newcommand{\new}[4]{\oldlongcommand[#1](#2:#3){#4}}
```

From the parameter text of your definition one can see that your macro `\new` does process four undelimited arguments.
Thus you need to provide four undelimited arguments and not just one.
Syntax with your definition is:

```
\new{A}{0}{4}{B}
```

---

Using delimited arguments implementing syntax `\new(A,0,4,B)` is feasible as well.
Be aware that with the example below nesting parenthesis is not a good idea.
Also spaces/space tokens surrounding the commas will not get removed.
Braces around the single comma-delimited arguments will get stripped off.

```
\newcommand\new{}%
\long\def\new(#1){\newinternal#1,}

\newcommand\newinternal{}%
\long\def\newinternal#1,#2,#3,#4,{\oldlongcommand[#1](#2:#3){#4}}%
```

---

`\new(A,0,4,B)`→
`\newinternal A,0,4,B,`→
`\oldlongcommand[A](0:4){B}`

With this approach one level of surrounding braces will be stripped off when `\newinternal` gathers its comma-delimited arguments – e.g.:

`\new({A},{0},{4},{B})`→`\oldlongcommand[A](0:4){B}` instead of
`\oldlongcommand[{A}]({0}:{4}){{B}}`.

With this approach spaces surrounding commata/parenthesis will not get removed  – e.g.:

`\new(A , 0, 4, B )`→`\oldlongcommand[A ]( 0: 4){ B }` instead of
`\oldlongcommand[A](0:4){B}`.